# Transmitting trace attributes using Operational Support in ProM

Tags: java

I am working on developing PlugIn using Operation Support but it looks like my traces are losing there attributes on  there way.

this Is my original trace that I want to send accross:

```
<log openxes.version="1.0RC7" xes.features="nested-attributes" xes.version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.xes-standard.org/">
<trace>
<string key="concept:name" value="1"/>
<string key="description" value="instance with id 1"/>
<event>
<int key="diagnosis" value="5"/>
<string key="stream:lifecycle:trace-transition" value="start"/>
<string key="concept:name" value="Receive Order"/>
<string key="lifecycle:transition" value="complete"/>
<date key="time:timestamp" value="2009-09-24T09:35:11.100+03:00"/>
</event>
</trace>
</log>
```

I sniffed the traffic and found out this is what is actually sent across.

```
<simpleQuery session="0" done="false" language="text/declaremonitor">
<trace>
<log openxes.version="1.0RC7" xes.features="nested-attributes" xes.version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.xes-standard.org/">
<trace>
<event>
<string key="concept:name" value="Receive Order"/>
<date key="time:timestamp" value="2009-09-24T09:35:11.100+03:00"/>
</event>
</trace>
</log>
</trace>
<items>
<log openxes.version="1.0RC7" xes.features="nested-attributes" xes.version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.xes-standard.org/"/>
</items>
<query class="java.lang.String">1</query>
</simpleQuery>
```

I tried to send the trace as a log item but the same thing happens with that. I need the attributes on the server side for analysis. By trace attributes I mean this part:

```
<string key="concept:name" value="1"/>
<string key="description" value="instance with id 1"/>
```